# Nhibernate search document id

Tags: nhibernate, lucene.net, nhibernate.search

If my class derives from Entity how do I define the documentid needed for nhibernate search/lucene.net using attributes?

Is this the best way:

```
[DocumentId]
public virtual int Id
{
    get { return base.Id; }
    protected set { base.Id = value; }
}
```

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 1):

If your class derives from a base Entity, you just put the attribute on the property of the base class :

```
public class Entity
{
    [DocumentId]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

You don't have to override it in derived classes.

Comment: Entity is part of NHibernate so I couldn't do what you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @csetzkorn : where is it located in NHibernate ?